# Area of a square, circle, and rectangle using inheritance in C++

Tags: c++

I am having an issue with my program in C++.  I need to find the area of a square, circle, and rectangle.  I have everything down with the circle and square but the rectangle and the shape (inheritance structure) are giving me the aforementioned issues.  I have been beating my head against a wall trying to figure this out so if anyone could help me I would greatly appreciate it.  My code is:

```
main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Circle.h"
#include "Square.h"
#include "Rectangle.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
double radius = 0;
double length = 0;
double width = 0;
Square square;
Circle circle;
Rectangle rectangle;
int option;

cout << "Calculating the Area" << endl << endl;

do
{
cout << "Pick a shape in which you would like the area of:" << endl;
cout << "1: Square" << endl;
cout << "2: Circle" << endl;
cout << "3: Rectangle" << endl;
cout << "4: Exit" << endl;
cout << "Please enter your choice: ";
cin >> option;

switch(option)
{
case 1:
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Please enter the length of one side of the square: " << endl;
        cin >> length;
        Square square(length);
        cout << "The area of the square is: " << square.getArea() << "\n\n";
        break;
    }
case 2:
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Please enter the radius of the circle: ";
        cin >> radius;
        circle.setRadius(radius);
        cout <<  "The area of the circle is: " << circle.getArea() << "\n\n";
        break;
    }
case 3:
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Please enter the length of one side of the rectangle: ";
        cin >> length;
        rectangle.setLength(length);
        cout << "Please enter the width of one side of the rectangle: ";
        cin >> width;
        rectangle.setWidth(width);
        cout << "The area of the rectangle is: " << rectangle.getArea();
    }
}
}
while (option != 4);
    cout << "Bye!" << endl;

}
```

shape.h

```
#ifndef SHAPE_H_INCLUDED
#define SHAPE_H_INCLUDED

class Shape {
public:
    double getArea();
};

#endif // SHAPE_H_INCLUDED
```

shape.cpp

```
#include "shape.h"

Shape::Shape() {
    area = 0;
}

double Shape::getArea() {
    return area;
}
```

rectangle.h

```
#ifndef RECTANGLE_H_INCLUDED
#define RECTANGLE_H_INCLUDED
#include <iostream>
#include "shape.h"

class Rectangle : public Shape
{
public:
Rectangle (double length = 0, double width = 0);
double getLength = 0;
double getWidth = 0;
void setLength(double length);
void setWidth(double width);
double getArea();
private:
double length;
double width;
};


#endif // RECTANGLE_H_INCLUDED
```

rectangle.cpp

```
#ifndef RECTANGLE_H_INCLUDED
#define RECTANGLE_H_INCLUDED
#include <iostream>
#include "shape.h"

class Rectangle : public Shape
{
public:
Rectangle (double length = 0, double width = 0);
double getLength = 0;
double getWidth = 0;
void setLength(double length);
void setWidth(double width);
double getArea();
private:
double length;
double width;
};


#endif // RECTANGLE_H_INCLUDED
```

I only included the ones I am having trouble with.  Seeing as how I know my other ones work and that this is a rewrite of a program I did last week.  Every time I try to build it I get these two errors.

Definition of implicitly-declared 'Shape::shape()'
area was not declared in this scope.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you declare the class (identically) in .h and .cpp? Include the .h into the .cpp

Comment: Error says that area is not declared. Your class declaration in shape.h does not declare the attribute "area". Rectangle does not either. So what is unclear?

Comment: Usually you only use objects if you have some form of state. (Unless you want to learn something and find a bad example use case). Shorter is better. ``double CircleArea( double r) { return 4 * atan(1.0) * r * r; }`` - Simple functions like that can replace any of your classes.

Answer (score 0):

1) change your Shape class as

```
class Shape {
public:
    Shape();
    double getArea();
    double area;
};
```

You have not defined constructor of class and `area`

2) You wrote same code in Rectangle.h and Rectangle.cpp. Write in Rectangle.cpp implementations of methods in class Rectangle

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys so much.  I have fixed my errors compiled and ran it and everything seems to be fine with it.  So once again thank you.  Also I put my .h file in my .cpp placeholder I am sorry about that.  Here is my real .cpp file for any of you wondering.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Rectangle.h"

using namespace std;

Rectangle::Rectangle(double len, double wid)
{
length = len;
width = wid;
}
double getLength();

void Rectangle::setLength(double len) {
length = len;
}

double getWidth();

void Rectangle::setWidth(double win) {
width = win;
}
double Rectangle::getArea() {
return width * length;
}
```